# Как сделать моментальное оповещение с сайта?

Tags: android

Меня заинтересовала тема, как можно сделать моментальное оповещение о новых сообщениях на сайте. Данные об сообщениях я получаю отправляя запрос на сайт каждые x-секунд, а есть ли другой способ это сделать?? и как сделано в вк и других подобных сервисах??

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/adventures-in-android-user-notifications/

Comment: Понял спасибо))

Comment: Только GCM уже устарел, новые проекты лучше делать на FCM, к тому же с ним все гораздо проще делается. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Есть очень много материалов, есть видеоматеры на канале в ютубе от самих разработчиков. Дока понятная, в консоле firebase можно делать мануальные рассылки, чтобы протестировать реализацию пушей в приложении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]